# Capabilities to run start-stop-daemon

Tags: c, linux

I would like to stop process (proc2) which was started by root
by my unprivileged process (proc1).

My process proc1 calls *execl("/bin/sh","sh","-c","/etc/init.d/proc2 restart",nullptr).*

and */etc/init.d/proc2 restart* calls *start-stop-daemon*

which fails because of lack of capabilities to kill proc2 (suid root)

What kind of capabilities have to be set to unprivileged process proc1 in order it could run start-stop-daemon (kill proc2)?

Comment: You could use `sudo` and set up a rule for that process.

Comment: Can you add an example of what you are doing right now?

Comment: I have to limit capabilities to the  required set i.e. unprivileged process could only kill privileged process.

Answer (score 1):

I will rewrite your question as *how is it possible to trigger an administrative task (requiring root priviledges) from a user lever process?*

The common way if to set a priviledged relay that will accept to be activated from a non priviledged task. There are two classical ways to do that in Unix/Linux world:

1. legacy way: an executale owned by root with the seuid bit set and executable only by a group of users allowed to execute the priviledged task. But setuid executables come with a high risk because any bug can lead to serious consequences. The well know `sudo` is just an example of such a *root seutid* executable but it has been extensively tested
2. the daemon way: a priviledged daemon waits for some *event* and executes the priviledged task. The interface with the unpriviledged world is only the *event*, so the risk is commonly seen as lower. The event is commonly the presence of a file in a directory, or a message written in a fifo file, or a network packet.

In either way, you must considere the security question: how to ensure only legitimate triggering of the priviledged task.

Comment: I was thinking about using capabilities utility. Unprivileged process would have to pass CAP_KILL through execl to bash. This way bash would be partially privileged and  could kill the privileged process.